# Retrieving user's email Google Login iOS

Tags: ios, google-plus

I am trying to find the email of the logged in account from the google login API in iOS using Swift.
The code i used is the same as given in the google Developers instruction page.

This is my code

> description = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@",
>   person.displayName,person.gender,person.ageRange.min,person.ageRange.max,person.emails,person.birthday];

The output when i print this "description" id is this:

> Karanvir Singh male 18 20 (
>       "GTLPlusPersonEmailsItem 0x7fbe4a67aee0: {value:\"karanvir95@gmail.com\" type:\"account\"}"
>   ) (null)

I want to know how i can remove the excess of output when i just want to know the email ID

i want the output as such:

> Karanvir Singh male 18 20 karanvir95@gmail.com 17/02/1995

Code as requested:

> ## import "ViewController.h"
>
> ## import "GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h"
>
> ## import "GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h"
>
> ## import "AppDelegate.h"
>
> @interface ViewController ()
>
> @end
>
> @implementation ViewController @synthesize signInButton; @synthesize
>   signOutHandle; @synthesize signInHandle; @synthesize infoLabel;
>   @synthesize description;
>   - (void)viewDidLoad {
>       [super viewDidLoad];
>       signOutHandle.hidden=true; }
>
> - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
>     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
>     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }
>
> -(void)refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn {
>       if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {
>           signOutHandle.hidden=false;
>           signInHandle.hidden=true;
>           infoLabel.text=description;
>       } else {
>
> ```
> } }
> ```
>
> - (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error: (NSError *) error {
>     NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
>     if (error) {
>         // Do some error handling here.
>     } else {
>
>   ```
>   GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
>   plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
>   [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];
>
>   GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];
>   query.collection=kGTLPlusCollectionVisible;
>   [plusService executeQuery:query
>           completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
>                               GTLPlusPerson *person,
>                               NSError *error){
>               if (error) {
>                   GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
>               } else {
>               //    [person retain];
>                   NSString *age = [NSString string];
>                   description = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", person.displayName,person.gender,person.ageRange.min,person.ageRange.max,person.emails,person.birthday,email];
>   ```
>
> NSLog(description);
>                       }
>
> GTLQueryPlus *query2 =
>                       [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
>                                                       collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];
>
> [plusService executeQuery:query2 completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed, NSError *error) {
>
> ```
>                             if (error) {
>
>                                 GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
>
>                             } else {
>                                 // Get an array of people from GTLPlusPeopleFeed
> ```
>
> NSArray* peopleList = peopleFeed.items;
>
> ```
>                             }
>                         }];
>                 [self refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn];
>             }];
> } }
> ```
>
> - (IBAction)signOutButton:(id)sender {
>       [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
>       [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect];
>
> ```
> signOutHandle.hidden=true;
> signInHandle.hidden=false;
> infoLabel.text=@""; }
> ```
>
> - (void)signOut {
>     [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut]; }
> - (void)disconnect {
>     [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect]; }
> - (IBAction)signedIn:(id)sender {
>     GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
>     signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
>     signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
>     signIn.clientID = kClientId;
>
>   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
>
>   signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
>     signIn.delegate = self;
>
>   signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoProfile, kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,kGTLAuthScopePlusMe,kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoEmail
>     ];
>     signIn.delegate = self;
>     [signIn authenticate];
>     email=(@"%@",signIn.userEmail);
>     NSLog(@" email:%@",email); }
> - (void)didDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)error {
>     if (error) {
>         NSLog(@"Received error %@", error);
>     } else {
>         NSLog(@"The user is signed out and disconnected.");
>         // The user is signed out and disconnected.
>         // Clean up user data as specified by the Google+ terms.
>     } }
>
> @end

Answer (score 0):

```
description = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", person.displayName, person.gender,person.ageRange.min,person.ageRange.max,person.emails.value,person.birthday];
```

And I want to note that your person has nil bithday

Comment: How so? The birthday should be available to be retrieved right? The google instructions say that it should. Could you help me further?

Comment: I don't know what google instructions says, but in your code person's birthday is nil:( Try to review your code, may be you do something wrong.

Comment: Oh, anyway.. the problem to be tackled first is the email ID retrieval.

Comment: code has been added :)
This is view controller.m file